# How to prevent url catchup from http canary or other packet capture or browser network

Tags: php, api, https

I make an api which is unique for all users of my app for getting data but i don't want to see this url to anyone because it contains data and user can run this in browser or use my api.
So my question is how to prevent my app from HttpCanary type app because any one can steal my api url and make request.
Please guide me how can i prevent my api.
I uses HTTPS.

Comment: Use (additional to the original TLS certificate checking) root certificate pinning in your app. Additionally you can use HTTPS with client certificate enforced by the server, accepting only the certificate contained in your app.